# postorder and preorder when some one child is in tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, traversal

I have preorder **abcdefg** and post order **cbfgeda** and have final tree as following image but because some of node has one child this is so hard. is there any one can help me a bit more detail how create final tree?

[image]

Comment: Postorder and Preoder or Postorder and Inorder? Your question's title and text are not asking the same thing.

Comment: We need inorder+preorder or inorder+postorder combination to create a tree(unless it is full binary tree). Are you trying to create a tree with preorder and postorder?

Comment: Please refer this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/

Comment: sure this is my sketch but not completely understand. this is unusual example for me.  sure this example is create with preorder and postorder. @ManikaSharma

Comment: uniqueness is not important here @ManikaSharma when a node has one children put it on right subtree.

Comment: Preorder+postorder combinations might give several binary tree.

Comment: sure.I'm familiar. how create one of them? logic? @ManikaSharma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224930/discussion-between-manika-sharma-and-maryam-panahi).

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a **Full Binary Tree** there is no unique solution for a given preorder and postorder of a tree.

**Edit:** since uniqueness is not the concern here you could also have a tree like this:
[image]

Since you are no longer have the exact order of left or right child node in a parent with a single child you could have that child in left or right.

**PS:** Steps to build this tree. we know `A` is the root since it is the last in postorder and first in the preorder, also from the preorder we know that `B` is a child of `A`, and also from the post order we understand that `D` is also a child of `A`. For the rest, you could recursively do steps like this for each node and its children. Consider that knowing `B` and `D` are a direct child of `A` you could find two sub tree `{B, C}` and `{D, E, F, G}`

Comment: please add one of them. uniqueness is not important here. creating one of these is enough here.

Comment: @MaryamPanahi ok, I'll edit my answer in few minutes.

Comment: ok, but I need some steps. for example start with a as a main root. then start with b as a left child...

Comment: @MaryamPanahi I've added some steps

Comment: "For the rest, you could recursively do steps like " exactly my problem is in this step. would you please continue one or two? ignore "Consider that knowing B and D"

Comment: @MaryamPanahi `B` and `D` are children of `A` so from preorder we could have two sub-preorders  `BC` and `DEFG`. Also from post order, we have `FGED` now do the exact same thing for these two sets of postorder and preorders.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following:

Preorder: abcdefg
Postorder: cbfgeda

You need to create a tree using them. Since you don't have inorder, you might be able to create several trees. Let us make the one you asked in the question.

Note:
Preorder =  Root Left Right
Postorder = Left Right Root

Step1: Deciding the root

Clearly, 'a' is the root

Step2: Deciding the left and right subtrees of 'a'

Since in the question, you have bc at one side, and rest at another, you can see Preorder and Postorder partioned as following respectively:

Preorder: |a| |bc| |defg|
Postorder: |cb| |fged| |a|

Now, apply the same technique to the rest of the tree, you will be able to create the one as you want.

Comment: would you please continue in chat?